# Como manter a option depois do refresh - asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, select

tenho um select, alguns options e um código jquery que no change do select, atualiza a tela com os dados da opção escolhida. A dúvida é, como eu mantenho a option depois do window.location?
*Obs:* estou utilizando **Asp.Net**

Código que tenho:
View:

```
<select id="servicos">
    @foreach (var i in servicos)
    {
        <option value="@Url.Content("~/servico/"+i.SiteInfoID+"/"+i.Titulo.html)">
            @i.Titulo
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

Js:

```
function ComboServicos() {
    $('#servicos').on('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val();
        if (url) {            
            window.location = url;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Você pode passar por querystring ou guardar no servidor, e depois pegar esse valor e deixar como selecionado com JS

Answer (score 0):

Por ter o parâmetro sendo enviado coloque o mesmo numa ViewBag por exemplo e recupere na View para que você possa filtrar fazendo um if para colocar o "selected" no option